# iOS fat binaries and thinning out

Tags: ios, lipo

I have an app that when using file, reports that it has 2 architectures in the Mach-O

```
iPad:~/map/MyApp.app root# file MyApp
   MyApp: Mach-O fat file with 2 architectures
```

EDIT - 
I have also checked this with Xcode's tool

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info MyApp
Architectures in the fat file: MyApp are: armv7 arm64
```

When I use otool to locate the architectures, I can see I have 2, an ARMv7(cpusubtype 9) and a ARM64 (cpysubtype 0)

```
iPad:~/map/MyApp.app root# otool -arch all -Vh MyApp
MyApp (architecture cputype (12) cpusubtype (9)):
Mach header
  magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC     ARM          9  0x00     EXECUTE    41       4760   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE

MyApp (architecture cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0)):
Mach header
  magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64 16777228          0  0x00     EXECUTE    41       5368   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE
```

However when I try to use lipo to thin out the binary, I get the following error

```
iPad:~/map/MyApp.app root# lipo -thin armv7 MyApp -output ~/map/myappv7
-sh: /usr/bin/lipo: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Any ideas why I can't think out this particular binary?
I did update my lipo binary as the previous one when used with armv7 said: no architecture of this type.

Comment: please use `file MyApp` to double check the contained slices.

Comment: Hi, i have already done that, it was at the top of the question: `MyApp: Mach-O fat file with 2 architectures`

Comment: Ah, sorry. That spits out more detailed information here. Maybe try to use Xcodes lipo: `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info MyApp`. Maybe also for thinning.

Comment: `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info MyApp`
`Architectures in the fat file: MyApp are: armv7 arm64`

Comment: And thinning with Xcode lipo? Same issue?

Comment: nope worked fine with Xcode lip. 
`$ file Myappv7`
`Myappv7: Mach-O executable arm`

`$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info Myappv7` 
`Non-fat file: Myappv7 is architecture: armv7`
any idea why it wouldn't work on the iPad?

Comment: No, but I had issue with lipo too in the past, that were no issues in Xcode lipo.

Comment: perfect, thanks, add an answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had several issues we could not explain in the past with `lipo`, which all of them were no issue using `Xcode`s `lipo`.

Give it a try:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -thin armv7 MyApp -output ~/map/myappv7
```